# Is the salt used with PBKDF2 secret?

Tags: key-derivation

I have two network endpoints that need to use the same derived key.  Can the server send the salt to the client 'in the clear'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Salts are only there to make a particular key derivation globally unique. They have no requirement of secrecy.